# Interval API calls in Redux-Observable

Tags: reactjs, rxjs, react-redux, redux-observable

I've started working with redux-observable in React and I stuck with interval API requesting.

It's code for my epic, which works good, but only for single request:

```js
const fetchPointValue = (action$) =>
  action$
    .ofType(actionTypes.REQUEST_POINT_VALUE)
    .mergeMap(action =>
          ajax.getJSON(`${API_SERVER_URL}/point/value/${action.payload.id}`)
            .map(response => receivePointValue(action.payload.id, response))
            .startWith(fetchingPointValue(action.payload.id))
    )
```

Now, i need to modify it to interval - if the action **REQUEST_POINT_VALUE** was called, i need to request value every ~5 seconds until **REQUEST_POINT_CANCEL** action.
Probably using **.takeUntil("REQUEST_POINT_CANCEL")** and **.interval(5000)** could resolve my problem, but I tried all possible  combinations, and still can't reach working version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve this using `.interval` and `.takeUntill`:

```js
action$
  .ofType(actionTypes.REQUEST_POINT_VALUE)
  .mergeMap(action =>
    Observable
      .interval(5000)
      .switchMap(/* make request here */)
      .takeUntil(action$.ofType(actionTypes.REQUEST_POINT_CANCEL))
  )
```

Take a look at the documentation and example here - [3.1 Cancellation](https://redux-observable.js.org/docs/recipes/Cancellation.html)

Comment: Great answer! Also: if you want the first request to start immediately instead of waiting for the first 5000 ms you can use `Observable.interval(5000).startWith(0)`

Comment: How would you catchError from within that switchMap though?